# OnClick analytics not tracking (Wordpress Yoast Analytics)

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, onclick

I have a Wordpress site using the Google Analytics plugin by Yoast.  At the bottom of my [website](http://www.deleddimmer.nl/) I have a few buttons/images going to sellers of our product.  I gave all those links unique Onclicks but they are just not working.

I've tried GA and gaq_push,  Onmousedown and onclick but not seems to work. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted.

Comment: After a long search I fixed it last year. The _GA tracker code was different in Yoast.  So tip: take a good look at the GA-code within the script your using!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the right code for Yoast is:

onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'your category', eventAction: 'your action', eventLabel: 'your label'});"

Notice the _gaTracker that is different from the standard GA trackingcode.